# Building a debian package for Mono GTK# app that doesn't rely on xamarin assemblies?

Tags: xamarin, mono, ubuntu-14.04

I built up a debian package for my solution so that I can actually distribute the app.

But when I put it on a clean machine I get the error:
Dependency is not satisfiable: libmono-corlib4.5-cil(>=4.0.0-alpha1)

If I do a sudo apt-get install mono-complete on the clean machine I can see that libmono-corlib4.5-cil is installed but it's listed as (3.2.8+dfsg-4ubuntu1.1, automatic). Looking at my dev machine the lib installed there is 4.0.5.1-0xamarin1, so it came from the monodevelop install.

Is there anyway to resolve this while creating the debian package?

Comment: You should be aware of the history that after some time in Mono 4.0 alpha, the Xamarin repo becomes de facto way to install Mono on Debian and Ubuntu. So if your app does target .NET 4.5 profile, aka corlib45, you should specify a dependency on Xamarin's mono den packages, instead of the old Mono 3.* from Debian central repo. That should be what RobertN's answer means

Comment: How can it be the defacto way to install Mono if you have to issue several commands from the command line to get mono to correctly pull down? Is there a way to update the installer to tell the Ubuntu software center where to look for the updated mono 4.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make your package dependent upon one (or more) of the libmono-xxxx packages that are available from Xamarin/Mono:

i.e.

```
libmono-corlib4.5-cil_4.0.5.1-0xamarin1_all.deb
```

That would require that you have the Mono-Project repos added to one of your `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` files....

Ref: http://download.mono-project.com/repo/debian/pool/main/m/mono/

Other than that, you would need to build, if possible, and package your project to ref. the Mono that is available in the std. Debian repo; i.e. 3.2.8

Comment: Looks like the toolset 3.2.8 won't build my app, or at least it's complaining about support for toolset v12. Assuming that some of my code uses some of the latest features, is there anyway to make distributing my app simple, or will it always require end users to manually add a reference to the mono repository?

Comment: Until the Debian std repos reference a 'newer' 4.x version of Mono, I personally do not know of a clean way. Just as you had to add it to your `sources.list.d` in order to develop against it, your end-users would have to do the same to run it. You could package all the needed Mono binaries (native and CIL based) within your `.deb` and reference those via MONO_PATH, etc.. but you would to handle the native ARCH types yourself within the various `.debs` that you would need to create. Either a cut/paste script, or write a .net app that updates theirs `sources.list.d` (with their perm of course)